# Why does nmcli list a different connected bitrate than the output of iwconfig?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

On a laptop with Pop!_OS 21.04

`nmcli dev wifi` outputs my connected network like so:

```
➜  ~ nmcli dev wifi
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                       MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       F0:23:B6:BB:78:9A  a-wifi-network             Infra  60    270 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
```

`iwconfig` prints different information:

```
➜  ~ iw dev wlp4s0 link
Connected to f0:23:b6:bb:78:9a (on wlp4s0)
    SSID: a-wifi-network
    freq: 5300
    RX: 12843437 bytes (9341 packets)
    TX: 1244809 bytes (8018 packets)
    signal: -40 dBm
    rx bitrate: 866.7 MBit/s VHT-MCS 9 80MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2
    tx bitrate: 866.7 MBit/s VHT-MCS 9 80MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2

    bss flags:  short-slot-time
    dtim period:    4
    beacon int: 100
➜  ~ iwconfig wlp4s0 
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"a-wifi-network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.3 GHz  Access Point: F0:23:B6:BB:78:9A   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=21 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:827   Missed beacon:0
```

This is on an [Intel 7265](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/83635/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-7265.html) built-in wireless adapter with a 2x2 radio.

How is the RATE from `nmcli` being calculated? It appears my wifi adapter is definitely capable of a higher rate, and is indeed connected at its max capable rate (867 Mbps) according to the other `iw` and `iwconfig` output.

However, if 270 Mbps is the current rate, why would I be transferring more data than I am supposedly capable of? (via iperf:)

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   538 MBytes   452 Mbits/sec   28             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec   537 MBytes   449 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

I know there are tons of variables, but I am hoping someone can help me understand these discrepancies.

Comment: In the worst case, you could avail yourself of the Open Source of these tools, download the source (Using `apt-get source <packagename>), and read, read, read.